# Will one trigger activate another trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

There are three tables `A`, `B`, `C` and two triggers `a`, `b`.

- When table `A` is updated, trigger `a` will be activated and update table `B`
- When table `B` is updated, trigger `b` will be activated and update table `C`

When I update table `A`, will table `C` be updated?

If not, how?

Comment: Yes, C should be updated.

Comment: [Nested Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx).  And what StevieG said is correct, your C table should be updated.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I will detail my question. When I insert a record into `A`, `A` is updated by a trigger. And it does! Then `B` should be updated by trigger `a`. But it doesn't.

Comment: To be honest triggers should be used very sparingly. They can be written incorrectly very easily and they can be an analysis nightmare because you forget they are there. In general if you have variables in your trigger it is highly likely they are written incorrectly. And nesting triggers is just painful from both a performance and maintenance perspective.

Comment: Yes, your triggers will fire as you expect. However in my experience this is a bad design and will cause great difficulty for those who have to maintain this code. I strongly recommend that you do NOT do this; instead, create a procedure which updates tables A, B, and C as you want and call this procedure rather than counting on nested triggers firing in the order you expect.

Comment: Absolutely agree, @SeanLange and Bob Jarvis.

Answer (score 5):

DML triggers can be nested up to 32 levels, however this can be switched off at the server level. So if it is important that tables B and C are updated, then you need to be certain that this setting will never be switched off, which could be difficult to ensure for the lifetime of an application.

See MSDN > Create Nested Triggers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190739.aspx

[image]